# Slicing a 3d image

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to slice a 3d representation of a image. Following factors is known:

- DimensionX
- DimensionY
- DimensionZ
- voxels[]

Voxels[] is an array of ushorts representing the grayscale of the pixel.

[image: Presentation of image]

Now i need to slice it in all possible directions. With let we say x, y or z.

[image: Z-Slice][image: Y-Slice][image: X-Slice]

I have tree implementations for this, but they have one problem, they don't work with dimensions that are not the same. (Except for get Z Slice, this is working perfectly).

These are the methods:

```
private ushort[] GetZSlice(int z, ushort[] voxels, int DimensionX, int DimensionY)
{
   var res = new ushort[DimensionX * DimensionY];
   for(int j = 0; j < DimensionY; j++)
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < DimensionX; i++)
       {
           res[j*DimensionX + i] = voxels[z*DimensionX*DimensionY + j*DimensionX + i];
       }
   }
   return res;
}
```

This method is working perfectly, it does not mather wat i choose as the dimension.

The next two methods, with x or y as depth poses as a harder problem.

```
private ushort[] GetYSlice(int y, ushort[] voxels, int DimensionX, int DimensionY, int DimensionZ)
{
    var res = new ushort[DimensionX * DimensionZ];
    for( int i = 0; i < DimensionX; i++)
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < DimensionX; j++)
        {
            res[j + i*DimensionX] = voxels[j * DimensionZ * DimensionY + Y*DimensionZ + i]
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private ushort[] GetXSlice(int x, ushort[voxels], int DimensionX, int DimensionY, int DimensionZ)
{
   var res = new short[DimensionY * DimensionZ];
   for(int i = 0; i < DimensionY; i++)
   {
       for(int j = 0; j < DimensionZ; j++)
       {
           res[j + i*DimensionZ] = voxels[i*DimensionY + j*DimensionZ*DimensionX + x]
       }
   }
   return res;
}
```

How could I improve the last 2 methods so it works with dimensions that are not equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make universal slice function using basis vectors? It will be far less code the manage.

Basicly you got `U,V` axises each mapped into `X,Y` or `Z`. And the Slice `W` is the third unused axis. So you just loop the U,V and leave `W` as is. Each `U,V` has a basis vector `(ux,uy,uz)` , `(vx,vy,vz)` that describes the increment change in `x,y,z` coordinates.

I encoded it into my **LED cube** `class` in **C++**...

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class LED_cube
    {
public:
    int xs,ys,zs,***map;

    LED_cube()              { xs=0; ys=0; zs=0; map=NULL; }
    LED_cube(LED_cube& a)   { xs=0; ys=0; zs=0; map=NULL; *this=a; }
    ~LED_cube()             { _free(); }
    LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    LED_cube* operator = (const LED_cube &a);
    void _free();
    void resize(int _xs,int _ys,int _zs);
    void cls(int col);                                  // clear cube with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void sphere(int x0,int y0,int z0,int r,int col);    // draws sphere surface with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void slice (char *uv,int slice,int col);            // draws (XY,XZ,YZ) slice with col 0x00BBGGRR
    void glDraw();                                      // render cube by OpenGL as 1x1x1 cube at 0,0,0
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void LED_cube::slice(char *uv,int slice,int col)
    {
    // detect basis vectors from uv string
    int ux=0,uy=0,uz=0,us=0;
    int vx=0,vy=0,vz=0,vs=0;
    int x=slice,y=slice,z=slice,u,v,x0,y0,z0;
    if (uv[0]=='X') { x=0; ux=1; us=xs; }
    if (uv[0]=='Y') { y=0; uy=1; us=ys; }
    if (uv[0]=='Z') { z=0; uz=1; us=zs; }
    if (uv[1]=='X') { x=0; vx=1; vs=xs; }
    if (uv[1]=='Y') { y=0; vy=1; vs=ys; }
    if (uv[1]=='Z') { z=0; vz=1; vs=zs; }
    // render slice
    if ((x>=0)&&(x<xs)&&(y>=0)&&(y<ys)&&(z>=0)&&(z<zs))
     for (u=0;u<us;u++,x+=ux,y+=uy,z+=uz)
        {
        x0=x; y0=y; z0=z;
        for (v=0;v<vs;v++,x+=vx,y+=vy,z+=vz)
          map[x][y][z]=col;
        x=x0; y=y0; z=z0;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see it is quite nice and simple ... and still can be optimized much more. here usage and output example:

```cpp
cube.resize(32,16,20);
cube.cls(0x00202020);
cube.slice("XY",5,0x000000FF);
cube.slice("XZ",5,0x0000FF00);
cube.slice("YZ",5,0x00FF0000);
cube.glDraw();
```

[image: example]

As you got your voxels stored in 1D array  then just compute the address from `x,y,z`. so `map[x][y][z]` will became your `voxels[(x*ys*zs)+(y*zs)+z]` or what ever combination of axis order you got. This can be totally encoded into the basis vectors so you can have `du=(ux*ys*zs)+(uy*zs)+uz` and `dv=...` and increment the address directly not needing any multiplication latter ...

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped alot!